Dripsy <> Expo 50
Dripsy is failing to compile on NextJS using Solito and Dripsy after upgrading to Expo 50 SDK
This is the error:
enter image description here
Using external babel configuration from /Users/monafang/Downloads/marketplace-dev/apps/next/.babelrc.json
 ⨯ ../../node_modules/dripsy/build/core/components/ScrollView.js:10:30
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   8 |     const containerSx = props.contentContainerSx && sx(props.contentContainerSx);
   9 |     const indicatorSx = props.indicatorSx && sx(props.indicatorSx);
> 10 |     return (<DripsyScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={props.contentContainerStyle && containerSx
     |                               ^
  11 |             ? [props.contentContainerStyle, containerSx]
  12 |             : containerSx || props.contentContainerStyle} indicatorStyle={props.indicatorStyle && indicatorSx
  13 |             ? [props.indicatorStyle, indicatorSx]
   automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
   automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
 ⨯ ../../node_modules/dripsy/build/core/components/ScrollView.js:10:30
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   8 |     const containerSx = props.contentContainerSx && sx(props.contentContainerSx);
   9 |     const indicatorSx = props.indicatorSx && sx(props.indicatorSx);
> 10 |     return (<DripsyScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={props.contentContainerStyle && containerSx
     |                               ^
  11 |             ? [props.contentContainerStyle, containerSx]
  12 |             : containerSx || props.contentContainerStyle} indicatorStyle={props.indicatorStyle && indicatorSx
  13 |             ? [props.indicatorStyle, indicatorSx]
 GET /_next/static/webpack/bb945efbbdff7f03.webpack.hot-update.json 500 in 8869ms
 GET / 500 in 10528ms
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 GET / 500 in 32ms

Here is my next.config.js
// This file sets a custom webpack configuration to use your Next.js app
// with Sentry.
// https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction
// https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter')
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  register: true,
  skipWaiting: false,
})

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  'three',
  'dripsy',
  '@emotion/styled',
  'react-native-web',
  'react-native',
  'solito',
  '@expo/match-media',
  'twrnc',
  'app',
  'stripe',
  'sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown',
  'zeego',
  'lottie-react-native',
  '@expo-google-fonts/inter',
  '@gorhom/bottom-sheet',
  '@gorhom/portal',
  '@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native',
  'react-native-reanimated',
  'react-native-screens',
  '@expo/html-elements',
  'react-native-gesture-handler',
  'react-native-autocomplete-dropdown',
  'react-native-blurhash',
  'react-native-confirmation-code-field',
  'react-native-country-codes-picker',
  'react-native-easy-grid',
  'react-native-fbsdk-next',
  'react-native-flagsmith',
  'react-native-google-places-autocomplete',
  'react-native-mask-input',
  'react-native-paper',
  'react-native-phone-number-input',
  'react-native-qrcode-svg',
  'react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked',
  'react-native-snackbar-component',
  'react-native-svg',
  'react-native-tab-view',
  'react-native-url-polyfill',
  '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view',
  'expo-application',
  'expo-auth-session',
  'expo-barcode-scanner',
  'expo-build-properties',
  'expo-cached-image',
  'expo-camera',
  'expo-clipboard',
  'expo-constants',
  'expo-dev-client',
  'expo-font',
  'expo-image',
  'expo-image-picker',
  'expo-linear-gradient',
  'expo-linking',
  'expo-random',
  'expo-screen-orientation',
  'expo-splash-screen',
  'expo-status-bar',
  'expo-web-browser',
  'react-native-pager-view',
  'react-native-safe-area-context',
  'styled-components',
  '@expo/next-adapter',
  '@react-native-firebase/auth',
  '@react-native-firebase/app',
  'react-instantsearch-native',
  'react-native-country-picker-modal',
  'expo-modules-core',
  'expo-image-manipulator',
  'expo-crypto',
  '@rneui/base',
  '@rneui/themed',
  'react-native-side-drawer',
  'nativewind',
  'expo-file-system',
])

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
//
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.experiments = {
      ...config.experiments,
      topLevelAwait: true,
      layers: true,
    }
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      },
    }
    return config
  },

  // transpilePackages: [
  //   'three',
  //   'dripsy',
  //   '@emotion/styled',
  //   'react-native-web',
  //   'react-native',
  //   'react-native-linear-gradient',
  //   'solito',
  //   '@expo/match-media',
  //   'twrnc',
  //   'app',
  //   'stripe',
  //   'sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown',
  //   'zeego',
  //   'lottie-react-native',
  //   '@expo-google-fonts/inter',
  //   '@gorhom/bottom-sheet',
  //   '@gorhom/portal',
  //   '@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native',
  //   'react-native-reanimated',
  //   'react-native-screens',
  //   '@expo/html-elements',
  //   'react-native-gesture-handler',
  //   '@react-native-async-storage',
  //   'react-native-autocomplete-dropdown',
  //   'react-native-blurhash',
  //   'react-native-confirmation-code-field',
  //   'react-native-country-codes-picker',
  //   'react-native-easy-grid',
  //   'react-native-fbsdk-next',
  //   'react-native-flagsmith',
  //   'react-native-google-places-autocomplete',
  //   'react-native-mask-input',
  //   'react-native-paper',
  //   'react-native-phone-number-input',
  //   'react-native-qrcode-svg',
  //   'react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked',
  //   'react-native-snackbar-component',
  //   'react-native-svg',
  //   'react-native-tab-view',
  //   'react-native-url-polyfill',
  //   '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view',
  //   'expo-application',
  //   'expo-auth-session',
  //   'expo-barcode-scanner',
  //   'expo-build-properties',
  //   'expo-cached-image',
  //   'expo-camera',
  //   'expo-clipboard',
  //   'expo-constants',
  //   'expo-dev-client',
  //   'expo-font',
  //   'expo-image',
  //   'expo-image-picker',
  //   'expo-linear-gradient',
  //   'expo-linking',
  //   'expo-random',
  //   'expo-screen-orientation',
  //   'expo-splash-screen',
  //   'expo-status-bar',
  //   'expo-web-browser',
  //   'react-native-ios-context-menu',
  //   'react-native-pager-view',
  //   'react-native-safe-area-context',
  //   'styled-components',
  //   '@expo/next-adapter',
  //   '@react-native-firebase/auth',
  //   '@react-native-firebase/app',
  //   'react-instantsearch-native',
  //   'react-native-country-picker-modal',
  //   'expo-modules-core',
  //   'expo-image-manipulator',
  //   'expo-crypto',
  //   '@rneui/base',
  //   '@rneui/themed',
  //   'react-native-side-drawer',
  //   'nativewind',
  //   'expo-file-system',
  // ],
  images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    domains: [
      'cdn.chec.io',
      'images.prismic.io',
      'images.ctfassets.net',
      's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
      'res.cloudinary.com',
      'drive.google.com',
      'images.vendoo.co',
      'source.unsplash.com',
      'cdn.shopify.com',
      'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
      'api.mapbox.com',
      'encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com',
      'encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com',
      'encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com',
      'encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com',
      'encrypted-tbn4.gstatic.com',
      'encrypted-tbn5.gstatic.com',
      'cdn.builder.io',
      'images.unsplash.com',
      'via.placeholder.com',
    ],
  },
}

require('dotenv').config({
  path: `../../.env`,
})

const env = {}

Object.keys(process.env).forEach((key) => {
  if (key.startsWith('NEXT_PUBLIC_')) {
    env[key] = process.env[key]
  }
})

module.exports = //withSentryConfig(
  withPlugins(
    [withTM],
    [
      withFonts({
        projectRoot: __dirname,
      }),
      [
        withPWA,
        {
          projectRoot: __dirname,
        },
      ],
      [withExpo], // MAKE SURE THIS GOES LAST!
    ],
    {
      ...nextConfig,
      env,
      async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/@:merchantid',
            destination: '/space/:merchantid',
          },
          {
            source: '/m/@:eventid',
            destination: '/market/:eventid',
          },
        ]
      },
    },
  ) /*,
  { silent: true,  },
  { hideSourceMaps: true }
)*/

/*
withPlugins(
    [
      [withFonts, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
      [withPWA, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
    ],
*/


Trying to run yarn at root and yarn web-dev
NextJS: latest
Expo: 50
apps/next package.json
{
  "name": "next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "slicemachine": "start-slicemachine",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006 ",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.5",
    "@happykit/flags": "^3.0.0",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.0.6",
    "@pdfme/generator": "^1.0.18",
    "@pdfme/ui": "^1.1.9",
    "@prismicio/client": "latest",
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.9",
    "@prismicio/next": "latest",
    "@prismicio/react": "latest",
    "@prismicio/slice-simulator-react": "^0.2.2",
    "@prismicio/svelte": "latest",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.2",
    "@segment/analytics-next": "^1.47.1",
    "@segment/analytics-node": "^0.0.1-beta.8",
    "@segment/snippet": "^4.15.3",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.43.0",
    "@slicemachine/adapter-sveltekit": "latest",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@twilio/conversations": "^2.3.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.22.1",
    "app": "*",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "dripsy": "^4.3.5",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.4",
    "graphql-middleware": "^6.1.28",
    "inngest": "^2.0.1",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.7",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.11.1",
    "motion": "^10.15.5",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "next-seo": "^5.15.0",
    "openai": "^4.21.0",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "pusher": "^5.1.1-beta",
    "pusher-js": "^7.5.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-instantsearch-core": "^7.6.0",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks-router-nextjs": "^6.43.0",
    "react-mailchimp-form": "^1.0.2",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.1.7",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "square": "^27.0.0",
    "taxjar": "^4.0.1",
    "type-graphql": "2.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "webpack": "^5.79.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.24.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.18.6",
    "@expo/next-adapter": "^6.0.0",
    "@prismicio/types": "^0.2.8",
    "@slicemachine/adapter-next": "latest",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.20",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^0.3.2",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/node": "17.0.21",
    "@types/raf": "^3.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.2",
    "customerio-expo-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "customerio-reactnative": "^2.3.3",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.76.1",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "slice-machine-ui": "latest",
    "storybook": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "storybook-addon-next": "^1.8.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}


apps/expo package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/mulish": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~8.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-native-menu/menu": "^0.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@segment/analytics-react-native": "^2.15.0",
    "@segment/sovran-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.37.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-terminal-react-native": "^0.0.1-beta.12",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "app": "*",
    "expo": "50.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.4.1",
    "expo-application": "~5.9.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.5.2",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.4",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-cached-image": "^45.1.1",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.8",
    "expo-clipboard": "~6.0.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.13",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-image": "~1.12.9",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~16.0.3",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-random": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.12",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.4",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.9.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.11.0",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-mmkv-storage": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "7.4.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.71.4",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/cli": "6.3.2",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^6.0.0",
    "metro": "0.76.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "metro-resolver": "0.76.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx expo start --dev-client -c --tunnel",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "AppTrackingTransparency",
    "BluetoothPeripheral",
    "Calendars",
    "Camera",
    "Contacts",
    "FaceID",
    "LocationAccuracy",
    "LocationAlways",
    "LocationWhenInUse",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Motion",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly",
    "Reminders",
    "Siri",
    "SpeechRecognition",
    "StoreKit"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "expo-app"
}


packages/app package.json:
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "app",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@algolia/autocomplete-js": "^1.7.1",
    "@algolia/autocomplete-plugin-query-suggestions": "^1.13.0",
    "@algolia/autocomplete-plugin-recent-searches": "^1.15.0",
    "@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic": "^1.7.1",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.1",
    "@apollo/server": "^4.3.3",
    "@as-integrations/next": "^1.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await": "^7.14.5",
    "@capsizecss/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@cloudinary/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.8.6",
    "@date-io/dayjs": "^2.15.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/match-media": "^0.3.0",
    "@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0",
    "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.6",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.7",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@graphql-tools/stitch": "^8.6.12",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.8",
    "@knocklabs/client": "^0.8.8",
    "@knocklabs/node": "^0.4.23",
    "@knocklabs/react-notification-feed": "^0.8.3",
    "@magicbell/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@magicbell/magicbell-react": "^10.3.2",
    "@magicbell/react-headless": "^4.2.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.159",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.3",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.10",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.2",
    "@pinecone-database/pinecone": "^0.0.10",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.14.0",
    "@prismicio/client": "latest",
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.9",
    "@prismicio/next": "latest",
    "@prismicio/react": "latest",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.96.5",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.15.15",
    "@reactour/tour": "^3.1.8",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@shopify/hydrogen-react": "^2023.4.4",
    "@shopify/shopify-api": "^7.3.1",
    "@snooper/react-native-video-processing": "^1.22.8",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.1.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.32.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/micro-cors": "^0.1.2",
    "@types/shippo": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@xstate/react": "^3.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.22.0",
    "apollo-datasource-mongodb": "^0.5.4",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^3.11.1",
    "array-to-image": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator": "^1.0.16",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.2",
    "blurhash": "^1.1.5",
    "bson": "^5.0.1",
    "camelcase-keys-deep": "^0.1.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cloudinary-build-url": "^0.2.4",
    "cross-undici-fetch": "^0.4.3",
    "csv": "^6.2.1",
    "dataloader": "^2.1.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.3",
    "dexie": "^3.2.2",
    "dexie-react-hooks": "^1.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "drei": "^2.2.21",
    "dripsy": "^4.3.5",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "firebase": "^9.8.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
    "flagsmith": "^3.14.1",
    "framer-motion-3d": "^11.0.3",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "google-search-results-nodejs": "^2.1.0",
    "graphql": "16.6.0",
    "graphql-rate-limit-directive": "^2.0.2",
    "graphql-scalars": "^1.17.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "haversine-distance": "^1.2.1",
    "html-to-text": "^9.0.5",
    "html5-qrcode": "^2.3.7",
    "image-js": "^0.35.3",
    "ip": "^1.1.8",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react": "^2.3.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "mailgun.js": "^8.0.1",
    "micro": "^9.3.4",
    "micro-cors": "^0.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.1.0",
    "nanoid": "^3.3.4",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "next-sitemap": "^3.1.44",
    "openai": "^4.21.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "pusher-js": "^8.3.0",
    "rc-drawer": "^5.1.0-alpha.1",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^13.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.5",
    "react-currency-input-field": "^3.6.5",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^2.7.0",
    "react-google-map-image": "^1.0.3",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.37.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.6",
    "react-instantsearch": "^7.5.0",
    "react-instantsearch-core": "^7.6.0",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.39.1",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks": "^6.42.0",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks-web": "^6.47.3",
    "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.39.1",
    "react-instantsearch-router-nextjs": "^7.5.0",
    "react-joyride": "^2.5.3",
    "react-keyboard-event-handler": "^1.5.4",
    "react-lottie-player": "^1.4.3",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.1.7",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-native-autocomplete-dropdown": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.3.2",
    "react-native-blurhash": "^1.1.10",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.1.8",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.2.0",
    "react-native-flagsmith": "^3.14.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.5.1",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "7.4.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-snackbar-component": "^1.1.12",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-video-processing": "^1.7.2",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-shepherd": "^4.1.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "react-three-fiber": "^6.0.13",
    "react-xarrows": "^2.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "replicate": "^0.16.1",
    "serpapi": "^2.0.0",
    "sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown": "^1.4.0",
    "shepherd.js": "^11.0.1",
    "shippo": "^1.7.1",
    "solito": "^3.2.6",
    "stripe": "^15.4.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7",
    "three": "^0.160.1",
    "timeago-react": "^3.0.5",
    "ts-tiny-invariant": "^2.0.4",
    "turnstone": "^2.2.0",
    "twilio": "^3.81.0",
    "twrnc": "^3.6.0",
    "unique-username-generator": "^1.1.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "victory": "^36.6.11",
    "xstate": "^4.35.2",
    "yet-another-react-lightbox": "^2.2.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zeego": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "resolutions": {
    "bson": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-toolbelt": "9.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@slicemachine/adapter-next": "latest",
    "@types/react-keyboard-event-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "schema-dts": "^1.1.0",
    "slice-machine-ui": "latest"
  }
}



Can you try getting rid of next-transpile-modules and use the new transpilePackages field on your next.config.js?
A number of these plugins you have in your next config are a bit out of date, but that is the most important one (assuming you just upgraded Next.js).

I tried the new transpilePackages field but it produced the same bug

did you uninstall next-transpile-modules?
